# Suspend on uncaught runtime exceptions in Eclipse Junit test runner

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, junit

Eclipse is not suspending on an uncaught runtime exception during debugging of a Junit test. I've tried:

- JRE 1.6 update 15 and 16
- Eclipse 3.5.0 and Eclipse 3.4.2
- Checked "Suspend on uncaught exception" for the exception and all runtime exceptions
- Checked "Keep JUnit running after a test run when debugging"
- Debugging when running only the test method, and the entire test class
- Suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125687/break-on-exception-in-eclipse-using-junit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370868/eclipse-debugger-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoint/)

All to no avail.

Debugging without the testrunner (ie: via a class with its own main method) works, ie: eclipse suspends on the line where the exception occurs.

Comment: Well? Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding `-consolelog` to your [**eclipse.ini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) file and check what your JUnit session produce there?
In [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg14483.html), the OP realized his xml file was referring to the wrong testing class.

Comment: Thanks VonC I tried that, but I there was no Junit output on the eclipse console tab.